# Is there a way to replace cells in Pandas based on their type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame from Pandas that I want to insert into a sqlite Database.
The dataframe I am using sometimes has lists in cells.
for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],'b': [1, [5,"name"]], 'c': [1.0, 2.0]})
```

Outputs

```
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1.0
1   2   [5,"name"] 2.0
```

These lists often contain dictionaries that the DB doesn't support and throws an error when inserted.

```
Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

The cells in question could be dictionaries or empty brackets, but when individually selected via .iloc their classes is always a list.
Is there a way I can replace all lists within my DataFrame with a Null value, empty string or empty list without iterating over all rows and columns?

I have tried to use .replace, .loc and .eq amongst others without much success.
The issue is that every example I've found is based on a mathematical condition e.g. < >, and I can't get the same results with the comparison of type I'm using.

for example:

```
df.loc[df["b"]==1] = 5
```

Outputs

```
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1.0
1   2   [5,"name"] 2.0
```

But

```
df.loc[type(df["b"])==list] = "NULL"
```

Outputs:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

I'm faily new to Pandas so any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `applymap` and then `np.where`:

```
# lambda x: type(x)==list
# would also work
df[:] = np.where(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)), 'NULL', df)
```

Output:

```
   a     b    c
0  1     1  1.0
1  2  NULL  2.0
```

Comment: Could also use `df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)), "NULL")` instead of combining `np.where` and overwriting the underlying data of `df`

Comment: @CameronRiddell yes, sometimes I forgot about the convenient mask and where. but reassignment is still necessary to update the dataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` `type` on each of the columns and check if it is list

```
df['b'].apply(type)
0    <class 'int'> 
1    <class 'list'>
Name: b, dtype: object
```

You can loop through the columns and update the values

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col].apply(type) == list, col] = 'NULL'

    a   b    c
0   1   1    1
1   2   NULL 2
```